# SQL problem: inner join gives me empty data set

Tags: mysql, sql

Please have a look at this question - https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/

I went with the approach of joining the table with itself and then putting my where condition to get the data I want. This is the query I wrote :-

```
SELECT wt1.Id FROM Weather wt1 
    inner join 
Weather wt2 on wt1.id = wt2.id
WHERE wt1.Temperature > wt2.Temperature AND 
      TO_DAYS(wt1.recordDate)-TO_DAYS(wt2.recordDate)=1;
```

Which gives me an empty data set.

However if I don't use join, and just use the Weather table twice, it works. My query :-

```
SELECT wt1.Id 
FROM Weather wt1, Weather wt2
WHERE wt1.Temperature > wt2.Temperature AND 
      TO_DAYS(wt1.recordDate)-TO_DAYS(wt2.recordDate)=1;
```

I want to know what difference the inner join makes and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your first query shouldn't have the `wt1.id = wt2.id` condition, and your second query should be using an explicit join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct version of your query, which neither of the two variants is actually doing, is this:

```
SELECT wt1.Id
FROM Weather wt1 
INNER JOIN Weather wt2
    ON wt1.Temperature > wt2.Temperature AND 
       TO_DAYS(wt1.recordDate) - TO_DAYS(wt2.recordDate) = 1;
```

This uses a proper explicit self-join with your conditions.  Note that the `wt1.id = wt2.id` join condition is dubious, since assuming `id` is a primary key or unique column, a given record can never have two different temperature values from the same column.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Now I get why the first query is wrong. But why do we need a join anyway? Second query will also work, without the self-join.

Comment: I would also suggest to write the second condition as `wt2.recordDate = wt1.recordDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY`, so it can benefit from an index.